# Add custom country to Carmen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

For my Ruby on Rails application, I have the [Carmen gem](https://github.com/jim/carmen) installed in order to access country data and auto create country fields (for example in the mailing address field for the user).

However, for the purposes of this application, Puerto Rico needs to be considered a separate country. Sometime last year Carmen was updated to remove PR from the list of countries but I was wondering if there was a way to add it back.

Example of how I'm currently using Carmen:

```
<%= f.country_select :country_residence, prompt: ' ' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable `PR` as a country, create a `config/carmen/world.yml` file with contents:

```
---
- alpha_2_code: PR
  _enabled: true
```

Then create an initializer file `config/initializers/carmen.rb` and add this to it:

```
Carmen.append_data_path File.expand_path('../../carmen', __FILE__)
```

To then remove `PR` from the `US` subregion list, create a file `config/carmen/world/us.yml` with contents:

```
---
- code: PR
  _enabled: false
```

Comment: Very well explained, this just took me a few seconds to implement and worked without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Puerto Rico from the list of countries as it is a subregion - Source change Log of the gem.

What you can do is enable the `world.yml` [in this file](https://github.com/jim/carmen/blob/master/iso_data/overlay/world.yml#L3).

I did the same and [here is my fork](https://github.com/ankit8898/carmen/commit/8204cd0863f16f1e04e30afc17822d336561284b)

The i installed the gem from my fork

```
1.9.3-p545 :005 > us = Country.named('Puerto Rico')
 => <#Carmen::Country name="Puerto Rico"> 
1.9.3-p545 :006 >
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *some* documentation about customizing your list of countries: [Overriding structural data](https://github.com/jim/carmen#overriding-structural-data).

It looks like you can define a custom overlay with a new definition for the [US](https://github.com/jim/carmen/blob/master/iso_data/base/world/us.yml) without Puerto Rico as an `outlying area`.

Also create a new definition for Puerto Rico with the required ISO codes.